# Automatically load multi-assets from a saved query into a PM'd WO

Tags: maximo

Maximo 7.6.1.1:

I have PMs that generate WOs.

And I have saved asset queries that pertain to each of the PMs.

- I plan to store the saved asset query names in a SAVEDQUERY field in the respective PMs.

Upon WO creation (via a PM), I want to automatically load the assets from the associated saved query into the multi-asset section of the WO.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You asked a clear question, and I have given an answer already, but this question feels too general for this forum. You've shown no evidence of trying something and not having it work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Use an Attribute-RunAction launch point on WORKORDER.PM to run a script that navigates back to the PM to get the saved query name then load that saved query's where clause and run it against the ASSET object. The caution is that the user the script will run as may have different permissions and data restrictions than the user who owns (and presumably tested) the saved query.